# Could not find any QT version when building openflipper on windows 7 64 bit machine

Tags: qt

I am now trying to build openflipper binary code on my computer. I got this error from cmake:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:66 (message):
  Could not found any QT Version.  Please specify QT5_INSTALL_PATH to build
  with QT5 or specify the QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE to the QT4 qmake
```

And I'm sure I've installed qt5.3, and already set the QTDIR and add qt directory to my system path.

Would anyone plz give a hand ? Thx.

openflipper version 2.1

Comment: Have you added QT5_INSTALL_PATH?

Comment: `set( CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${QT5_PATH} )` where `QT5_PATH` is a path to your compiled Qt folder.

Comment: You'll save yourself a lot of trouble to forget about `QTDIR`. It's not necessary for anything. Just as you shouldn't have to add any of Qt's `bin` directories to your path. When invoking qmake, you need to invoke it from a specific Qt installation manually, by providing full path. From that point onwards, everything will just work without changes to your environment other than to have the SDK tools in the path.

Comment: thx for the advice, when i try to install qt5.4 to my computer, it automatically solve the problem. Zen's suggestion may help, but Kuba's suggestion seems not quite useful since i'm building openflipper source file.

Answer (score 0):

Looking back on this question, I think a proper fix should be adding a new CMake entry as QT5_ROOT=${path-where-Qt5Config.cmake-lives}.

In my case, it should be Qt5_ROOT=C:\Qt\5.9.1\msvc2015_64\lib\cmake\qt5.
You can do this either from Cmake-gui or passing it into terminal as `cmake -DQT5_ROOT=${path-where-Qt5Config.cmake-live} ${path-to-your-source-file}`